# Geometry node : delete splines with a certain number of points

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is there a way to delete splines that have a certain number of points within geometry nodes? Basically I'm trying to delete all splines that have under 5 points, to keep only the longer ones
Thank you for reading this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I found a way which was super easy. The node I was missing was simply the spline length node (I feel stupid now). Here is the setup I used
[image]